# Combining a $within $box search with a $in search which both have to be valid in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

My situation:
I have a collection with addresses in my database and I want to show these on a google maps as marker, but only within the coördinates of the displayed map and only if the address id is in my list with ids that should be displayed.

I have 2 seperate queries that work perfectly fine on their own.

```
// Find within ID's
db.addresses.find({
    _id : { $in: [ ObjectId("ID1"), ObjectId("ID2") ] }
})
```

This query returns 2 addresses with the given IDs, as expected.

```
// Find within area
db.addresses.find({
    location : { $within: { $box : [ [ 51.498761244224,4.3004231168717 ], [ 51.494099036558,4.2811004831284 ]] } }
})
```

This query returns about 15 addresses, which also include the address with ID1, which is within the given coördinates.

I want to combine these 2 queries to 1, which only returns the addresses with de given ID's that are within the given coördinates.

I tried the following:

```
// Find within area within ids
db.addresses.find({
    $and : [
       {location : { $within: { $box : [ [ 51.498761244224,4.3004231168717 ], [ 51.494099036558,4.2811004831284 ]] } } },
       {_id : { $in: [ ObjectId("ID1"), ObjectId("ID2") ] } }
    ]
})
```

This returns no rows. I was expecting 1 address, the one with ID1.

I tried searching on Google but I can't seem to find how I should combine these two queries.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use $and operator. You can't use geospatial queries in the $and operator. Check [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572). Try this:

```
db.addresses.find({
       location : { $within: { $box : [ [ 51.498761244224,4.3004231168717 ], [ 51.494099036558,4.2811004831284 ]] } } ,
       _id : { $in: [ ObjectId("ID1"), ObjectId("ID2") ] } 
})
```

Not sure if the above mentioned issue affects the `implicit and` we are using here.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried it like you suggested, still no results.

Comment: @BasvandenWijngaard strange. If you are sure that the queries have intersecting documents, this should work. And [you can't](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4572) use geospatial queries in the $and operator. Not sure whether that's the same for the `implicit and` as above.